# Reuse aggregate function value multiple times in the same query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a transaction report export from our system to another, and have a query like the following

```
SELECT {otherFields}, 
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN FLAG='D' then -amount else amount) > 0 
THEN SUM(CASE WHEN FLAG='D' then -amount else amount) ELSE 0 AS DEBIT
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN FLAG='C' then -amount else amount) <= 0 
THEN -SUM(CASE WHEN FLAG='D' then -        amount else amount) ELSE 0 AS CREDIT
FROM table INNER JOIN .....
```

The query works as expected however i have conducted the same sum 4 times, first to determine if its a net debit or credit on the account then again to get insert that net amount into the debit or credit columns.

Is there a way to capture the value of the sum in the select cause and have it reused (or sql server smart enough to cache it) so that my query would be something like.

```
    CASE WHEN @NET_TOTAL > 0 THEN @NET_TOTAL ELSE 0 AS DEBIT,
    CASE WHEN @NET_TOTAL <= 0 THEN @NET_TOTAL ELSE 0 AS CREDIT
```

Comment: have you looked to see if you could break it up into sub queries using a cte?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your goal, then you should use a Common Table Expression.

Comment: I had taken a look at CTE but have never really used one. Will it be able to use values from the main query, or does the CTE have to be a self contained query

Comment: A CTE is a query that creates a new table that is only stored for the lifetime of the whole query.  You would create the CTE as essentially the same query, but with only the Aggregate functions.  You would do the case statements in the main query.  If I had your full query I could help more.

Comment: Ended up re-writing query to use a cte. I was able to use the CTE to do the heavy lifting so that my select just massaged the data into the third party format. Didn't see much of an improvement performance wise but huge for readability.

Comment: I've been worrying less and less about individual query performance over the years due to the fact that server performance has been greatly outpacing the size of datasets for most business uses.  I do still try to limit recursion because that can really bring your server to a halt. For scientific and engineering applications it's a different story, though.

Answer (score 0):

CTE / Temp Tables are the best approach to this problem. You may see some performance degradation however your code will be readable and maintainable.